# Can I get an unbound function from a bound function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, bind, ecmascript-5

I'm getting my head wrapped about currying and other techniques using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).
It seems extremely useful to change function scope (i.e., `this` value) in certain situations.

However [it looks like you can't change the scope with `bind`](http://jsfiddle.net/dXq2E/1/) once you already did so:

```
function f = obj.method.bind(42); 
function g = obj.method.bind('Hi');

function f2 = f.bind('Hi'); // “this” is still 42
```

Is it possible to retrieve the original unbound function from a bound function at all?

Comment: @Martin: I'm creating a fiddle right now. It seems like a very simple question to someone who knows the answer, hence why I posted a question without prior research.

Comment: @Martin: I just [checked my assumptions](http://jsfiddle.net/dXq2E/) and it really looks like I can't change the scope with `bind` twice. So, is it possible at all? Is there some kind of `unbind`?

Comment: Yup, I'm with Felix on this one - no way, José

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible, but then again, I can't come up with a situation where it would ever be needed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What the `bind` method basically does is something like (not exactly, because arguments are sliced to exclude the context):

```
function bind(context) {
    var self = this;
    return function() {
        self.apply(context, arguments);
    }
}
```

So basically it's returning another function which will call itself with the given context and arguments. If you then `bind` it again, you'll be binding this newly created function, which will be as if `bind` was implemented like:

```
 function bind(context) {
    var self = this;
    return function() {
        self.apply(context, arguments);
    }.bind(otherContext);
}
```

But because the inner function returned by bind acts as a closure where the original context is the one binded first (`self`), that one will be the context in with your function will be really executed.

Answer (score 26):

I thought it would be useful to illustrate [Win32's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523370/458193) with a picture.

A wrapper generated by `bind` makes sure your function is called with given context *no matter what*.
Such wrapper will **always ignore its own context**.

Given a chain of wrappers, any context but the innermost is lost.
Therefore, there is no way to change the context once it has been set using `bind`.

[image: Chained bind calls]

Answer (score 3):

This would actually solve you issue

```
const bind = Function.prototype.bind;
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'bind', {
    value: function () {
        const result = bind.apply(this, arguments);
        result.source = (this.source || this);
        return result;
    }
});
```

Now you can get the `source` property to get the original function.
This could cause other issues, but performance does not seem to be one of them, https://jsperf.com/bind-override/1

Both IE, Edge, Firefox and Chrome seems to get the same result, sometimes the normal version is faster and sometimes the overridden is faster.

Comment: Would be nice to know why this was downvoted so i can improve the answer!

Comment: My guess is that you're getting downvoted because this changes the default behaviour of the `Function` prototype, which is generally frowned upon. I like your solution and I'm going to use this in my code. :)

Comment: Also, I'd recommend changing the line `result.source = this` to `result.source = (this.source || this)`, so that the source will remain the same no matter how many times a function is bound.

Comment: @Mr.X Great idea, i have made the changes you suggested.